# How to get IE cookie from Interop.SHDocVw

Tags: c#

We are using shdocvw.dll to navigate an https url.

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer browser = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
browser.Navigate2(url,refVal,refVal,refVal,refVal);
browser.DocumentComplete += documentComplete
```

On Document complete, we are trying to capture the document cookie but it is returned as null.